# Chart Control needs an HTTP Handler?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis-7, .net-4.0, charts

I have an VS2010 ASP.NET 4 web site app, to which I added the new Chart control.

When I deployed it to our web server, we get a" Internal Server Error 500." message.

I noticed that the following lines were added to the web.config since the last release, related to the chart control:

```
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
       validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
```

If I remove this added code from the web.config, the site works--Except for the charting functionality.

How do I get the site and the chart page to work?

This is not an issue on IIS versions < 7.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure you comment out the entry in the system.web section:

```
<httpHandlers> 
<add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, 
System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
validate="false"/> 
</httpHandlers>
```

And make sure the system.webserver section has the following:

```
<handlers> 
<remove name="ChartImageHandler" /> 
<add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST"
path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, 
System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" /> 
</handlers>
```

Comment: Will the same settings in <system.webServer> work in IIS 7 classic pipeline mode?

Comment: I use above settings but it didn't work for me but when i add this code within handlers after <add name ="chartImageHandler".... /> it worked for me. Hope it will help other also if they face the same issue **<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>**

Answer (score 0):

Check the event log for the server in question. The web servers 500 error will be an application exception in the event log. Fix the cause of that exception and you should be good to go.

Comment: I looked. I dont sdee anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
In Web Config :

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/></assemblies></compilation>
    </system.web>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;" />
  </appSettings>


  <system.web>



      <httpHandlers>
        <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
      </httpHandlers>
      <pages>
        <controls>
          <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        </controls>
      </pages>
    </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ChartImageHandler"/>
      <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```